# Send Object Over Java Socket

Tags: java, sockets, exception

I have a class name player

```
public JLabel imagen;

public String Nombre;

public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height, Icon icono, String name){
    imagen = Player(x, y, width, height, icono);
    Nombre = name;
}
public JLabel Player(int x, int y, int width, int height, Icon icono){
    JLabel imagen = new JLabel(icono);
    imagen.setLocation(x, y);
    imagen.setSize(width, height);
    return imagen;
}
```

(It is for creating a new player)

I also have a client class:

```
public class Cliente implements Runnable {

    String host;
    int puerto;
    Player mensaje;

public Cliente(int purto, Player mensaje, String host){
    this.puerto = purto;
    this.mensaje = mensaje;
    this.host = host;
}
@Override
public void run() {
    DataOutputStream out;

    try {
        Socket sc = new Socket(host, puerto);
        out = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
        ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);
        
        objectOutputStream.writeObject(mensaje);
        
        sc.close();

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
}
}
```

And im using objectOutputStream but it says that it

"java.io.NotSerializableException: objects.Player"

And I want to send my player to the server but it says that exception!

Also if you need here is the server class

```
public class Servidor extends Observable implements Runnable {

    int puerto;

public Servidor(int puerto) {
    this.puerto = puerto;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    ServerSocket servidor = null;
    Socket sc = null;
    DataInputStream in;

    try {
        servidor = new ServerSocket(puerto);
        System.out.println("server started");

        while (true) {
            sc = servidor.accept();

            in = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
            ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(in);

            Player players = null;
            try {
                players = (Player) input.readObject();
                System.out.println(players.Nombre);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            }

            this.setChanged();
            this.notifyObservers(players);
            this.clearChanged();

            sc.close();
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
    }
}
}
```

and also if you want here are the lines of code that send the request to the client class

```
    Cliente c = new Cliente(5000, new Player(x, y, width, height, icon, "name of the player"), "the ip");
    Thread t = new Thread(c);

    t.start();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you forgot to make the Player object Serializable, thus code is throwing `java.io.NotSerializableException`

If you need to send some object over network then the object need to be Serializable.

> Serialization is the process of taking the memory data structure of an
> object and encoding it into a serial (hence the term) sequence of
> bytes. This encoded version can then be saved to disk, sent across a
> network connection, or otherwise communicated to a recipient. (from
> Wikipedia.org)

I have updated the code

Player.java

```
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Player implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public JLabel imagen;

    public String Nombre;

    public Player(int x, int y, int width, int height, Icon icono, String name) {
        imagen = Player(x, y, width, height, icono);
        Nombre = name;
    }

    public JLabel Player(int x, int y, int width, int height, Icon icono) {
        JLabel imagen = new JLabel(icono);
        imagen.setLocation(x, y);
        imagen.setSize(width, height);
        return imagen;
    }
}
```

Cliente.java

```
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Cliente implements Runnable {

    String host;
    int puerto;
    Player mensaje;

    public Cliente(int purto, Player mensaje, String host) {
        this.puerto = purto;
        this.mensaje = mensaje;
        this.host = host;
    }

//  @Override
    public void run() {
        DataOutputStream out;

        try {
            Socket sc = new Socket(host, puerto);
            out = new DataOutputStream(sc.getOutputStream());
            ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(out);

            objectOutputStream.writeObject(mensaje);

            sc.close();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cliente c = new Cliente(5000, new Player(1, 2, 3, 4, null,
                "Holis Studios"), "localhost");
        Thread t = new Thread(c);

        t.start();
    }
}
```

Servidor.java

```
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.Observable;

public class Servidor extends Observable implements Runnable {

    int puerto;

    public Servidor(int puerto) {
        this.puerto = puerto;
    }

//  @Override
    public void run() {
        ServerSocket servidor = null;
        Socket sc = null;
        DataInputStream in;

        try {
            servidor = new ServerSocket(puerto);
            System.out.println("server started");

            while (true) {
                sc = servidor.accept();

                in = new DataInputStream(sc.getInputStream());
                ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(in);

                Player players = null;
                try {
                    players = (Player) input.readObject();
                    System.out.println(players.Nombre);
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                }

                this.setChanged();
                this.notifyObservers(players);
                this.clearChanged();

                sc.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Servidor server = new Servidor(5000);
        Thread t = new Thread(server);

        t.start();
    }
}
```

Compiling the code:

```
javac.exe -cp . Player.java

javac.exe -cp . Servidor.java

javac.exe -cp . Cliente.java
```

Run:

```
java.exe -cp . Servidor
server started

java.exe -cp . Cliente
```

Output appearing on Servidor console:

```
server started
Holis Studios
```